# Date format though Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have implemented the `Datepicker` though `Jquery`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy'));;                                                                          
    });
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<div> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
</div>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

But the format of the date is `MM/DD/YYYY` and i want a format as `DD/MM/YYYY`.
i have tried to implement the `formatdate` of `datepicker method` but the particular doesn't appear. thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```